# Can't find Wifi Direct option in settings

Tags: settings, wifi-direct

I have Sony Live with Walkman mobile phone, Android version 4.0.4.
I can't find WiFi direct option in settings. There are only mobile networks, tethering/portable hotspot and two more useless options are there.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but I find [Gesture Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch) invaluable in finding hidden settings that aren't where I expect to find them.

Comment: NO, it didn't helped but I thinks that probably the wifi Direct also depends on hardware configurations

Comment: Is it dependent on hardware support?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there isn't any option like that. Its missing. There were lots of complaints about 4.0.4 Update for Live with Walkman that `Wifi Direct is missing`.

look at [here](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/39932).
Also look at this review of update..:

```
First of all thanks for the wonderful update and congratulations.  
Few things i would like to share with sony:  
1. We cannot uninstall Appextra from the phone at all and should have that option  
2. Phone dialer is laggy it takes almost 3-5 sec to open the dialer plz fix that  
3. really time to update the kernel to 3.0 as i have ssen the ICS running on kernel 3.0 with same hardware specification as Xperia 2011 portfolio has and the phone runs better than it is currently running on 2.6.32.9-pref version  
4. Wifi Direct option is missing as its a feature of ICS 4.0.X fix that in next update so that we get that option as well  
5. please provide us option to move some of the internal app to sd card as it will save more space on phone memory.  
6. when tried to update the inbuilt application such as liveware manger Error Unable to do that it says “An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed.  
7. Google talk application sometimes says we are offline even though we are not.
8.live wallpaper gets force close all of a sudden many times.  
9.screen shot option is complicated and should be in the same way as it was in GB  
10.photos when viewed from xperia gallery should provide more detail info for the photos and videos as it shows in galary app.  
11. A normal sound recorder application should be their to record voices or conversation
12. A file manger application should be their.
```

May be sony will fix it in next update.

Answer (score 0):

Try going onto your wifi settings page. When your on the list of available connections there may be a button at the bottom of the screen titled "Wifi Direct".

..That's how it is on my S3 anyway

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question, the OP clearly stated *I can't find WiFi direct option in settings* plus, also stated *Android version 4.0.4*...

Comment: No there is no such button anywhere as I mentioned but I found the button in one of my friend's samsung galaxy tablet which has same version of android(4.0.4). as of mine.

Comment: The older versions of android has it in 'more settings'.. since the update my phone has moved it to the wifi settings. I know plenty of people who are unaware of where it moved too and I had to direct them! I missed the bit where he stated the Android version..

Sorry for trying to help 't0mm13'...